# NullPointerException from AbstractAggregatingMessageGroupProcessor when using Kafka Message Bus

Tags: spring, apache-kafka, spring-xd

Pretty sure this a bug in Spring XD.

Running Spring XD 1.3.0.RELEASE in SingleNode mode. All configuration is default except I am using Kafka instead of local transport. Relevant XD configuration:

```
spring:
  profiles: singlenode
xd:
  transport: kafka
  messagebus:
    kafka:
      brokers:                                 localhost:9092
      zkAddress:                               localhost:2181
      mode:                                    embeddedHeaders
      offsetManagement:                        kafkaTopic
      socketBufferSize:                        2097152
      offsetStoreTopic:                        SpringXdOffsets
      offsetStoreSegmentSize:                  25000000
      offsetStoreRetentionTime:                60000
      offsetStoreRequiredAcks:                 1
      offsetStoreMaxFetchSize:                 1048576
      offsetStoreBatchBytes:                   16384
      offsetStoreBatchTime:                    1000
      offsetUpdateTimeWindow:                  10000
      offsetUpdateCount:                       0
      offsetUpdateShutdownTimeout:             2000
      default:
        batchSize:                 16384
        batchTimeout:              0
        replicationFactor:         1
        concurrency:               1
        requiredAcks:              1
        compressionCodec:          none
        queueSize:                 8192 # must be a power of 2
        maxWait:                   100
        fetchSize:                 1048576
        minPartitionCount:         1
        durableSubscription:       false
```

Create a stream using an aggregator (this one straight from the reference docs):

```
stream create --name aggregates --definition "http | aggregator --count=3 --aggregation=T(org.springframework.util.StringUtils).collectionToDelimitedString(#this.![payload],' ') | log" --deploy
```

Then send 3 POST's:

```
xd:> http post --data Hello
xd:> http post --data World
xd:> http post --data !
```

The result is this stacktrace:

```
2015-12-10T17:07:11-0800 1.3.0.RELEASE ERROR pool-13-thread-1 listener.LoggingErrorHandler - Error while processing: KafkaMessage [Message(magic = 0, attributes = 0, crc = 344940496, key = null, payload = java.nio.HeapByteBuffer[pos=0 lim=81 cap=81]), KafkaMessageMetadata [offset=2, nextOffset=3, Partition[topic='aggregates.0', id=0]]
org.springframework.messaging.MessageHandlingException: error occurred in message handler [org.springframework.integration.config.AggregatorFactoryBean#0]; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:139) ~[spring-integration-core-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.AbstractDispatcher.tryOptimizedDispatch(AbstractDispatcher.java:116) ~[spring-integration-core-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.doDispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:147) ~[spring-integration-core-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.dispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:120) ~[spring-integration-core-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:77) ~[spring-integration-core-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:442) ~[spring-integration-core-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:392) ~[spring-integration-core-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:115) ~[spring-messaging-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:45) ~[spring-messaging-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.send(AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.java:105) ~[spring-messaging-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.sendOutput(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:231) ~[spring-integration-core-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.produceOutput(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:154) ~[spring-integration-core-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.sendOutputs(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:102) ~[spring-integration-core-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:105) ~[spring-integration-core-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:127) ~[spring-integration-core-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.FixedSubscriberChannel.send(FixedSubscriberChannel.java:69) ~[spring-integration-core-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.FixedSubscriberChannel.send(FixedSubscriberChannel.java:63) ~[spring-integration-core-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:115) ~[spring-messaging-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:45) ~[spring-messaging-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.send(AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.java:105) ~[spring-messaging-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.MessageProducerSupport.sendMessage(MessageProducerSupport.java:105) ~[spring-integration-core-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.integration.kafka.inbound.KafkaMessageDrivenChannelAdapter.access$300(KafkaMessageDrivenChannelAdapter.java:43) ~[spring-integration-kafka-1.3.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.integration.kafka.inbound.KafkaMessageDrivenChannelAdapter$AutoAcknowledgingChannelForwardingMessageListener.doOnMessage(KafkaMessageDrivenChannelAdapter.java:171) ~[spring-integration-kafka-1.3.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.integration.kafka.listener.AbstractDecodingMessageListener.onMessage(AbstractDecodingMessageListener.java:50) ~[spring-integration-kafka-1.3.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.integration.kafka.listener.QueueingMessageListenerInvoker$KafkaMessageDispatchingSubscriber.onNext(QueueingMessageListenerInvoker.java:221) [spring-integration-kafka-1.3.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.integration.kafka.listener.QueueingMessageListenerInvoker$KafkaMessageDispatchingSubscriber.onNext(QueueingMessageListenerInvoker.java:209) [spring-integration-kafka-1.3.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at reactor.core.processor.util.RingBufferSubscriberUtils.route(RingBufferSubscriberUtils.java:67) [reactor-core-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at reactor.core.processor.RingBufferProcessor$BatchSignalProcessor.run(RingBufferProcessor.java:789) [reactor-core-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) [na:1.8.0_66]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [na:1.8.0_66]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_66]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_66]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_66]
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at org.springframework.integration.aggregator.AbstractAggregatingMessageGroupProcessor.aggregateHeaders(AbstractAggregatingMessageGroupProcessor.java:115) ~[spring-integration-core-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.integration.aggregator.AbstractAggregatingMessageGroupProcessor.processMessageGroup(AbstractAggregatingMessageGroupProcessor.java:79) ~[spring-integration-core-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.integration.aggregator.AbstractCorrelatingMessageHandler.completeGroup(AbstractCorrelatingMessageHandler.java:648) ~[spring-integration-core-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.integration.aggregator.AbstractCorrelatingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractCorrelatingMessageHandler.java:405) ~[spring-integration-core-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:127) ~[spring-integration-core-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
    ... 32 common frames omitted
```

Is this a Spring XD bug? Is there a workaround?

---

More details.

The header causing the NPE is `kafka_messageKey`. The value of this header is `null` so [AbstractAggregatingMessageGroupProcessor:115](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/blob/master/spring-integration-core/src/main/java/org/springframework/integration/aggregator/AbstractAggregatingMessageGroupProcessor.java#L115) throws the NPE.

Looking further at [KafkaMessageBus](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-xd/blob/master/spring-xd-messagebus-kafka/src/main/java/org/springframework/xd/dirt/integration/kafka/KafkaMessageBus.java#L1040), it appears that the Kafka [messageKey](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-kafka/blob/master/src/main/java/org/springframework/integration/kafka/support/ProducerConfiguration.java#L93) is intentionally set to null from the Producer.

Comment: You'll probably going to need to prove to us that the indicated variable shouldn't be null.

Comment: I also tried starting XD with `xd.messagebus.kafka.mode=raw` and specifying `--outputType=application/octet-stream` on each module but this resulted in the same error.

Comment: Looks it is the bug in the KafkaMessageDrivenChannelAdapter when it populates messageKey to the Map unconditionally. Please, raise a Jira on the matter agains spring-integration-Kafka. I'll come back to you tomorrow with some workaround.

Comment: @ArtemBilan I have opened [INTEXT-210](https://jira.spring.io/browse/INTEXT-210)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug in Spring XD. See [INT-3908](https://jira.spring.io/browse/INT-3908) for details.

---

Following the [suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34216534/953327) by Marius, the following is a suitable workaround:

Edit `$XD_HOME/modules/processor/aggregator/config/aggregator.xml` to include:

```
<channel id="aggregatorInput"/>

<header-enricher input-channel="input" output-channel="aggregatorInput" default-overwrite="true">
    <header name="kafka_messageKey" value="."/>
</header-enricher>

<aggregator input-channel="aggregatorInput" output-channel="output"
    correlation-strategy-expression="${correlation}"
    release-strategy-expression="${release}" expression="${aggregation}"
    send-partial-result-on-expiry="true" expire-groups-upon-completion="true"
    message-store="messageStore">
</aggregator>
```

**Note**: using a `header-filter` will not work as the mechanism SI uses for [removing a header](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-messaging/src/main/java/org/springframework/messaging/support/MessageHeaderAccessor.java#L347) will only [remove the header if it is not already null](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-messaging/src/main/java/org/springframework/messaging/support/MessageHeaderAccessor.java#L309).

---

Alternatively, if you don't want to edit the module XML directly, you could use [Module Composition](http://docs.spring.io/spring-xd/docs/current/reference/html/#composing-modules) to include a Header Enricher before the standard aggregator module.

```
module compose --name kafa-aggregator --definition "header-enricher --headers={\"kafka_messageKey\":\"'.'\"} --overwrite=true | aggregator --count=3 --aggregation=T(org.springframework.util.StringUtils).collectionToDelimitedString(#this.![payload],' ')"

stream create --name aggregates --definition "http | kafa-aggregator | log" --deploy
```

Comment: Ah, I see - sorry that the filter didn't eventually work, but at least glad to having set you on the right track. Probably the best course of action on the long run will be to update the Spring Integration version of Spring XD, once a release with the fix is out.

Answer (score 2):

One possible workaround would be to add a header filter to the aggregator module, by inserting a header filter at the beginning of  `$XD_HOME/modules/processor/aggregator/config/aggregator.xml`, by altering its start as follows:

```
<channel id="input" />

<channel id="aggregatorInput"/>

<int:header-filter input-channel="inputChannel"
    output-channel="aggregatorInput" header-names="kafka_messageKey"/>

<aggregator input-channel="aggregatorInput" output-channel="output"
            correlation-strategy-expression="${correlation}"
            release-strategy-expression="${release}" expression="${aggregation}"
            send-partial-result-on-expiry="true" expire-groups-upon-completion="true"
            message-store="messageStore">
    </aggregator>

... rest of the module definition remains unchanged ...
```

As for how to fix this issue on the log run, I will comment on the JIRA issue.

Cheers,
Marius

Comment: Somewhat ironically, this does not work because SI removes a header by setting it's value to null.

Comment: Actually, to be more accurate, SI only removes the header if it is not already null. Take a look at the lines I linked to in [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34274232/953327) and you will see.